# comparing two apk files to check the difference between then(size difference of 1 kb)

Tags: android, compare, apk, diff

I have two apks, which basically are exactly the same but their size differs by 1 KB. I would like to check what this difference is. Is there any tool available for this purpose?

When i unzip the apk's , the size turns out to be exactly the same.

Answer (score 5):

this is what u looking  for **[apkanalyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer)**

Answer (score 1):

An APK file is essentially an archive, therefore try run [zipcmp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zipcmp) command on the apks you interested in. It shows the sizes and hashes of the files that differ within an archive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to compare the content of apks.

1. Unzip apks and compare `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` files - it will show which file differs. If none, the zip structure differs (not suremaybe zip headers?).
2. [apktool decode](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/) both apks to folders - it will result in files with decoded resources, manifest and classes to folders.
3. directory compare (i.e. [meld](https://www.tecmint.com/compare-find-difference-between-two-directories-in-linux/)) bot folders to investigate the difference in file content.